# How to compress image while taking images from gallery

Tags: android, file, bitmap, imageview, bitmapfactory

I want to take to photo from and save it to sdcard and after that when it comes to images from gallery its size should be compressed so that images should be fit image view and no error of out memory error and easily goes to other activity

thanks

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545246/how-to-compress-image-size hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this ; it may help you..

```
public class bitmaptest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        // load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
               R.drawable.android);

        int width = bitmapOrg.width();
        int height = bitmapOrg.height();
        int newWidth = 200;
        int newHeight = 200;

        // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        // createa matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // rotate the Bitmap
        matrix.postRotate(45);

        // recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, 
                          width, height, matrix, true); 

        // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap 
        // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

        // set the Drawable on the ImageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);

        // center the Image
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

        // add ImageView to the Layout
        linLayout.addView(imageView, 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
                )
        );

        // set LinearLayout as ContentView
        setContentView(linLayout);
    }
}
```

And also you can check with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourimage, 160, 160, true);`

Comment: my prblm is dat when i take this images to second activity it show me out of memory error byte allocation

Answer (score 0):

you can add following code in your project to compress image from path

you just need to pass image path that you have chosen from gallery

```
    public static String compressImage(Context context,String imageUri) {

        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri,context);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

        float maxWidth,maxHeight;

        //if the image has width>height, we'll want the final image to be somewhere in the dimension of 720x1280
        //if the image has width>height, we'll want the final image to be of 1280x720
        //if the image has width=height(square), we'll want the final image to be of 1280x1280

        if(actualHeight>actualWidth){
            maxHeight = Constants.maxHeightFloat;
            maxWidth = Constants.maxWidthFloat;

        }else if(actualWidth>actualHeight){
            maxHeight = Constants.maxWidthFloat;
            maxWidth = Constants.maxHeightFloat;
        }else {
            maxHeight = Constants.maxHeightFloat;
            maxWidth = Constants.maxHeightFloat;
        }
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;

            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(filename!=null)
            addImageToGallery(filename,context);

        return filename;

    }
```