# App crashes on adding image view

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, imageview

My app works finely with 11 image views. But upon adding 1 more image view to it, app crashes. I found some similar answers to this problem in stack overflow itself, but couldn't find my exact solution.

Main Activity:

```
    package com.trendsetter.vyshnav.eatutor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


    public class BreakfastActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_breakfast);
}

    }
```

XML file:

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/i1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d1a"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d1b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/i2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/i3" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d3a"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d3b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/i4" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d4a"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d4b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/i5" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d5a"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d5b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t6"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/i6" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d6a"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d6b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t7"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/i7" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d7a"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d7b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t8"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/i8" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d8a"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d8b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t9"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/i9" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d9a"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d9b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t10"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/i10" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d10a"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d10b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t11"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/i11" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d11a"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d11b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Logcat:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9815052 byte allocation with 4194208 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
```

Comment: post your logcat please.

Comment: `@drawable/i3` Remove `3` Number from image name

Comment: k..just a sec please

Comment: as same as `@drawable/i6` remove`6`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thats wont cause crash

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Why should the numbers be removed?

Comment: @driodev i know.Actually i obey Naming conventions .

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9815052 byte allocation with 4194208 free bytes and 5MB until OOM

Comment: @vvv I assume that .At first reduce image size

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio

Comment: @Intelli: How can I do that? Is it using inSample? If so can you please give me the exact solution?

Comment: Try adding `android:largeHeap="true"` in `Application` element of `Manifest`

Comment: @cricket_007: just a minute...let me check that

Comment: Plus, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your Scrollview, but it appears a ListView or RecyclerView would be the appropriate layout to use

Comment: @ShreeKrishna: yhea i tried that, but still the error is present

Comment: @vvv `Thrown when a request for memory is made that can not be satisfied using the available platform resources. Such a request may be made by both the running application or by an internal function of the VM.` Check above Link `Duplicate`

Comment: @cricket_007: isn't scroll view more suitable for this since its a simple app.

Comment: @vvv Reduce image resolution please.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: let me check it and come back

Comment: No, it isn't more suitable because all views are loaded in memory at once

Comment: guys, i have mentioned in my question that I have found similar answers (Duplicate stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/). The problem is I am unable to apply it. I get confused.

Comment: @cricket_007: thankyou....that was a valuable info...

Comment: @cricket_007: what problem will occur if all views load into memory a once?

Comment: Your current problem is more likely to occur...  OutOfMemoryError

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: Can u please post the full code if possible?

Comment: @cricket_007: Can u please post the full code if possible?

Comment: I can't provide code because I don't know what you're trying to achieve and I don't have your images.

Comment: @cricket_007: its ok...anyway thnks fr yr help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because your image size is larger than 2Mb so try to compress the image in your baseAdapter:
    yo can follow this link to compress the image :
    [How to compress image size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545246/how-to-compress-image-size)

Answer (score 0):

Adding AndroidManifest.xml file and solve issue:

```
<application
             ....
             ....
             android:largeHeap="true"

 </application>
```

Comment: your image size is large above 2MB or high

Comment: Please read the comments above.  "yhea i tried that, but still the error is present"

Answer (score 0):

Your Scrollview seems to be a collection of multiple sets of 3 TextViews plus an ImageView.

I suggest defining a custom Object with 3 String values and an int value that will hold the `R.drawable` integer value for an image.

Then, you can define a custom XML row a single object. And "bind" each object to the Views via a ListView + ArrayAdapter or RecyclerView.

In order to fix the out of memory error, you should use an image loading library like Picasso or Glide to load the integer resource id mentioned earlier into the ImageView rather than load the full, raw image into memory.