# Multipart request with retrofit 2.0 Android Taking too much time to request

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I try to make a multipart request with retrofit 2.0 to upload an image to my server.

For now I have RequestBody with my image

```
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
```

Then I create from data in this way

```
imagenPerfil = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("user[image]",file.getName(),requestFile);
```

My retrofit interface

```
@Multipart
@Headers({"Accept: application/json","X-OS:android","X-Api-Version:1","X-FIREBASE-TOKEN:token"})
@POST("/update_user_details")
Call<UserDetailAddResponse> uploadMulFile(@Header("X-User-Token") String token_header, @Header("X-User-Email") String email,
                                          @PartMap Map<String,Map<String,Object>> object,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

request taking too much time to go on server or in the end it stop or don't send request on server..what i have to do
would i use this in another Thread or is it okay ?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question in your question...

Comment: are you sure your internet is working as expected?

Comment: yaa it's working properly ..

Comment: What is your image size?

Comment: it's around 2545514 it's in long data type is there any other way to know ??

by this link i compress my image
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49557959/10279394

Comment: You are keeping constant width 612.0f and height 816.0f for the image. It could be approximately around 3MB(more or less not sure). But image size is the problem in your case. Try some other compression technique.

Comment: can you see the logs if it is being uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the timeouts in the Retrofit settings.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()  
    .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

Maybe it help for you!

More: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-customize-network-timeouts

Comment: Sorry @ILLIADEREVIANKO for late reply .......i got stuck in another problem can u plzz tell one thing about retrofit it possible tu send this json to server{       
“user” :{         “name” : “helo”,
        “image” : “”,
language_id” : 1,
“relation_id”: 2
} 
}

Comment: @RahulChaudhary can I help you more?

Comment: Thankyou @ILLIA DEREVIANKO but the problem is solved.....if i stuck anywhere i'll definatrly ask you :D

Comment: @ILLIADEREVIANKO, what about a retrofilt multipart request of a large image, where server process its size, nudity check and s3 upload and respond back with url strings. Are you proposing these timeouts are optimal ?

Comment: @binrebin of course no. It's a flexible configuration and you should adapt it according to your requirements