# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) in AsyncTask

Tags: android

My app has been crashing in some devices using `mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, quality, bos)`

```
public ISOMsg isoMsgChequeStop(StopChequePaymentParams stopChequePaymentParams) {
    ISOMsg m = new ISOMsg();
    String accountNumber = stopChequePaymentParams.getAccountNumber();
    String reasonCode = stopChequePaymentParams.getReasonCode();
    Integer chequeStartNo = stopChequePaymentParams.getChequeStartNo();
    Integer noOfLeaves = stopChequePaymentParams.getLeavesCount();

    try {

        m.setMTI(MSGComposerConstants.MTI_TX); //MTI
        //m.set(2, "0000000000000000"); //Primary Account Number/Customer ID
        m.set(2, stopChequePaymentParams.getInitiator()); //Primary Account Number/Customer ID/ Card number (length=16)
        m.set(3, MSGComposerConstants.PROCESSING_CODE_CHQ_STOP); //Processing Code
        m.set(4, "0000000000000000");
        String stan = Util.padRight(stanGenerator.generateSTAN(), " ", 12);
        m.set(11, stan); //System Trace Audit Number
        m.set(12, Util.getCurrentDateTime()); //Local Transaction Date And Time
        m.set(17, Util.getCurrentDate()); //Capture Date
        m.set(32, MSGComposerConstants.ACQUIRING_II_CODE); //Acquiring Institution Identification Code
        m.set(37, "412812134941"); //constant
        m.set(41, "00390039"); //atm id
        m.set(42, Util.padRight("1000008", " ", 15)); //atm id
        m.set(43, "LAXMI ATM");

        if (stopChequePaymentParams.hasPartners()) {
            m.set(46, stopChequePaymentParams.getPartnerPattern());
            //m.set(46, "99524D000000000000000000000000D0000000000000000524");
        }

        m.set(49, stopChequePaymentParams.getTransactionCurrencyCode());

        String field62 = Util.padLeft(chequeStartNo.toString(), " ", 16) +
            Util.padLeft(noOfLeaves.toString(), "0", 4) +
            Util.padRight(reasonCode, " ", 5);

        m.set(62, field62);
        m.set(102, accountNumber);
        m.set(123, MSGComposerConstants.DELIVERY_CH_CTRL_ID); //Delivery Channel Controller ID

    } catch (ISOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return m;
}
```

**Error message:**

```
Error
'HUAWEI/TRT-L21A/HWTRT-Q:7.0/HUAWEITRT-L21A/C185B173:user/release-keys'
2019-01-11 11:04:03.684 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2019-01-11 11:04:03.684 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2019-01-11 11:04:03.684 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG: pid: 24319, tid: 24440, name: AsyncTask #4  >>> example.dell.com.personalstickerforwhatsapp <<<
2019-01-11 11:04:03.684 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x84f80000
2019-01-11 11:04:03.684 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG:     r0 84f7f003  r1 00000800  r2 00000200  r3 84f7f803
2019-01-11 11:04:03.684 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG:     r4 84e1fe00  r5 00000200  r6 84e1fff0  r7 84f7ffe3
2019-01-11 11:04:03.684 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG:     r8 00000ffc  r9 84f7f803  sl 00000200  fp 00000001
2019-01-11 11:04:03.684 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000200  sp 877f3f20  lr 84e1fc00  pc b3723464  cpsr 600e0010
2019-01-11 11:04:03.689 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-01-11 11:04:03.689 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 002e4464  /vendor/lib/libskia.so
2019-01-11 11:04:03.689 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00300210  /vendor/lib/libskia.so
2019-01-11 11:04:03.689 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 002ffa3c  /vendor/lib/libskia.so
2019-01-11 11:04:03.689 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 002ffb24  /vendor/lib/libskia.so (WebPPictureImportRGBA+36)
2019-01-11 11:04:03.689 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0029cf37  /vendor/lib/libskia.so (_ZN18SkWEBPImageEncoder8onEncodeEP9SkWStreamRK8SkBitmapi+302)
2019-01-11 11:04:03.689 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000a5fa5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
2019-01-11 11:04:03.689 24443-24443/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 745f88d3  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot-framework.oat (offset 0x17ce000)
```

Comment: Compress bitmap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545246/how-to-compress-image-size.

Comment: Did you find the solution?